# Why does passing and changing a class self-variable with an external function work for manipulating iterables but not variables?

Tags: python, class, methods, self

I ran into a very hard to track down bug in my program where a class self-iterable was manipulated by an external function and discovered that some self-variables can be changed and some can't.
Is it possible to manipulate a single self-variable like an int with an external function without passing the entire class?

Here's some example code:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_var = 0
        self.my_str = "Foo"
        self.my_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
        self.my_list = [1, 2, 3]
        self.my_dict = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
        self.manipulate_1()
        self.manipulate_2()

    def manipulate_1(self):
        external_1(self.my_var, self.my_list, self.my_str, self.my_tuple, self.my_dict)
        print(self.my_var)
        print(self.my_list)
        print(self.my_str)
        print(self.my_tuple[0])
        print(self.my_dict["one"])
        #prints 0, 15, Foo, 1, 15
    def manipulate_2(self):
        external_2(self)
        print("\n" + str(self.my_var))
        # prints 1

def external_1(instance_var, instance_list, instance_str, instance_tuple, instance_dict):
    instance_var += 1
    del instance_list[0]
    del instance_list[0]
    instance_list[0] = 15
    instance_str = "Bar"
    list(instance_tuple)[0] = 15
    instance_dict.update({"one": 15})


def external_2(instance):
    instance.my_var += 1


a = TestClass()
```

The list can be manipulated by deleting entries just by passing it as an argument, while the variable can only be manipulated while passing `self`.

Is there a way to manipulate a single self-variable. If not, does passing `self` come with any performance or other issues?
I.E., if I want to manipulate a self-variable, is using a method mandatory?

Comment: That's because in python list are passed by reference by default, whereas immutable types are passed by value. When you pass `self` to the `external` method you're passing the instance of the class, hence you're modifying the class variable.

Comment: @toti08 plain wrong. All arguments are passed exactly the same way, whether mutable or not. The difference is between rebinding a local name vs mutating an object.

Comment: Yes, ok, but if you pass immutable objects then the call acts like a call by value, whereas this does not happen with mutable objects.

Comment: This still have nothing to do with "pass by value" or "pass by reference" or the argument's being mutable or not (except of course for the fact that you cannot mutate an immutable type but that's orthogonal).

Comment: @MarcusGrass the answer to your question is here: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Interesting problem. My initial thought is to just return the value in the function then assign the return value like so `self.my_var = self.manipulate_1()`

Comment: However: I think if you want to modify a class variable the best is to write a method, something like `modify_my_var`, so that it's explicit what you want to do and do not create hidden behavior in your class.

Answer (score 3):

Python's arguments passing works the same for all objects - the original object is passed (not "a copy of", not "a reference to", not "a pointer to" - it IS the object itself that is passed), regardless of the object's type, whether it's mutable or not etc. These objects are then bound to their matching parameter's names as local variables.

The difference you observe is actually the result of the difference between to totally distinct operations: rebinding a (local) name and mutating an object.

Since parameters are local variables (local names actually) rebinding a parameter in your function's body only make this name point to another object, and does not impact the original argument (except for decreasing the reference counter). So obviously this has absolutely no effect outside the function itself.

Now when you *mutate* one of your argument, since you are working on the very object you passed to the function, those changes are, very obviously, visible outside the function.

Here:

```
def external_1(instance_var, instance_list, instance_str, instance_tuple, instance_dict):
    # this one rebinds the local name `instance_var`
    # to a new `int` object. Doesn't affect the object
    # previously bound to `instance_var`
    instance_var += 1

    # those three statement mutate `instance_list`, 
    # so the effect is visible outside the function
    del instance_list[0]
    del instance_list[0]
    instance_list[0] = 15

    # this one rebinds the local name `instance_str`
    # to the literal string "Bar". Same as for `instance_var`
    instance_str = "Bar"

    # this one creates a list from `instance_tuple`, 
    # mutate this list, and discard it. IOW it eats a 
    # couple processor cycles for nothing.  
    list(instance_tuple)[0] = 15

    # and this one mutates `instance_dict` so the
    # effect is visible outside the function
    instance_dict.update({"one": 15})
```

And here:

```
def external_2(instance):
    # this one mutates `instance` - it's actually
    # syntactic sugar for 
    # `instance.__setattr__("my_var", instance.__getattribute__("my_var") + 1))`
    instance.my_var += 1
```

As I already mentionned a couple times in the comments, all this (and much more) [is explained in full details in Ned Batchelder's reference article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score -1):

**Please see the addendum.**

<s>This is normal and expected behavior. Its because of the difference between sending reference and sending values.</s>

With `external_1(self.my_var, self.my_list)`:

- You send `self.my_var` which is *value*. This means that `external_1` receives only a value. That value is then local to the function, so the class has no way of knowing if it changed. Try this to see this working:

  def external_1(instance_var, instance_list):
      instance_var += 1
      print('This will print one:', instance_var)
      del instance_list[0]
      del instance_list[0]
- The variable 'self.my_list`is an *reference*. This means you're sending the address of where to find the list. So the function`external_1` will go to that address and change the list values there.

With `external_2(self)` you send a reference to `external_2` of the entire class. So it does exactly the same as with `self.my_list`.

If you still don't fully understand, don't worry, it took me quite some time to understand these kind of references (or pointers). There is millions of tutorials and videos about how they work.

**Addendum:**

@bruno is correct when saying that I'm not explaining it correct in the technical sense, and how Python actually handles all the variables. I'm simply trying to explain what happens as an overview, and coming from the C world, it's how I understand it.

Comment: There's no pointer in Python, and all arguments are passed exactly the same way. Please check your facts.

Comment: By pointer, or reference, it's essentially the same thing. My jargon might be incorrect, but the working behind it it sound.

Comment: Alright, I now understand why they're different, is there a way to pass an argument by ref or by pointer specifically, like & or * in c++?

Comment: It's still plain wrong if you cal it a reference, and that's still not how it works. The difference is between rebinding a local name and mutating an object.

Comment: @MarcusGrass this answer is PLAIN WRONG, period. Read this to understand how Python works: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay, let me see if I've got it now, if I send a variable of some immutable datatype such as an int or str, the value of that just get copied to the new function variable. But if the object is mutable it can be changed in the function, the solution then being passing a single-variable list to the function?

Comment: @Marcus Python is not that simple. If you want to "pass a value by reference" then place the variable in a class, and then send the class to the function, as per this [question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pass-a-variable-by-reference-in-Python). Or by using a list, as you proposed now.

Comment: @MarcusGrass Nope. All arguments are passed exactly the same way, as explained in the article I linked to and that you __MUST__ read if you want to understand how Python variables work (actually Hein should read it too obviously). The difference is only between __rebinding a name__ and __mutating an object__.

Comment: @HeinWessels do yourself a favour and go read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - so you will have the correct mental model of how python variables work. Trying to reason about Python variables in terms of C or C++ or Java is a waste of time.

Comment: @bruno, thank you for the info. I did read it, and I do agree with you. But I also quote from the article: `Exactly how the name refers to the value isn’t really important. If you’re experienced with the C language, you might like to think of it as a pointer, but if that means nothing to you then don’t worry about it.`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Okay I read it and please correct me if I'm wrong here: python variables are names pointing to some object. When we do a function call our function argument name points to that same object. If that object is mutable, like a list, we can make change to the list that the passed variable points to. Now the object that the self-variable points to has changed value, but is still the same object.
Sounds like pointers.

Comment: If names where pointers rebinding a name in a function would affect the object that was passed. It doesn't, hence those are NOT pointers. You really have to forget everything about C-type variables (symbolic names for memory locations) to understand Python variables (names bound to objects, where names are scoped but objects are not).

Comment: @MarcusGrass "the object that the self-variable points to has changed value" => no. You did not rebind the object, you mutated it, which is not the same thing.